# Differentiate between QML array and map/object types from C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qml

Consider QML such as:

```
Item {
  objectName: "myitem"

  // arrays  
  property var arr1: [1,2,3]
  property var arr2: ['a','b','c']
  property var arr3: [{'a':1,'b':2},{},{}]

  // maps/objects
  property var map1: {'a':1,'b':2}
  property var map2: {'l1':[1,2,3], 'l2':[4,5,6]}
}
```

How can I determine if a property (by name) is a list or a map from C++?

For example:

```cpp
QObject* item = root->findChild<QObject*>("myitem");
QVariant value = item->property(propName);
bool isList = value.canConvert<QVariantList>();
bool isMap = value.canConvert<QVariantMap>();
```

gives true for `isList` and `isMap` for all of those properties.

The `value.type()` doesn't seem to be of much help either (just gives 1024 in both cases - `QMetaType::User`).

I don't know in advance the type of the QML property.

Also: if I use Javascript to assign the properties from arrays and objects within Javascript code, will the types be the same as the statically specified QML literals above?

Is `QJSValue` of any use here?

FYI: I am interfacing with another type system that also represents simple types, and arrays and maps of them, and I wish to dynamically convert to/from QML array & map properties.  Including nested arrays of maps and maps with array values etc. (though map keys are always strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when Qt converts QML Javascript engine arrays and objects back to `QVariant`, it doesn't immediately convert them into `QVariantList` or `QVariantMap`, but just wraps the QML Javascript engine type.

Noting that `value.type()` yields `QMetaType::User` and `value.userType()` yields the value of `qMetaTypeId<QJSValue>()`, the `QVariant` is just wrapping a `QJSValue`.  Calling `value.toList()` or `value.toMap()` will convert it as expected if you know which to call.

However, we can cast it as follows to determine which it is:

```cpp
QVariant variant = qvariant_cast<QJSValue>(value).toVariant();
bool isList = variant.type() == QMetaType::QVariantList;
bool isMap = variant.type() == QMetaType::QVariantMap;
```